# how to make ` __dirname ` point to the current folder?

Tags: javascript, node.js

`structure:`

```
utils

  __dirname.js

app.js
```

`dirname.js:`

```
  import { dirname } from 'path';
    import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';
    
    export const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));
```

`app.js:`

```
import { __dirname } from './utils/__dirname.js';
console.log(__dirname);
```

`console output:`

```
src/utils
```

when importing it from another file it always points back to the utils folder, How to make it point to the folder of call?

Comment: What in the heck are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: __dirname doesn't work in ES module scope, so i'm trying to implement it so i don't have to write the same things over and over since __dirname is frequently used

Comment: Do you understand what __dirname does at runtime?

Comment: https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/modules.html#__dirname

Comment: Well you're using the `import.meta.url` of the *dirname.js* module, so what else would you expect? Make it a function where you can pass the `import.meta.url` of the current module as an argument.

Comment: Maybe i'm failing to phrase the question
I need to write those three lines every time I want to use __dirname

import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

const __dirname = dirname(fileURLToPath(import.meta.url));

is there is a way to make it as a utility function and use it when ever I want instread of typing those 3 lines everytime I want to use dirname ?

Comment: You can pass `import.meta.url` to an exported function from `dirname.js` that does the same thing, but I'm not sure what you were expecting with your current code.

Comment: You can't put that code in another module because that other module will always create `__dirname` in the context of that other module, not in the context of the calling module.  As has already been said here, about the best you can do is to create a exported function that you pass `import.meta.url` to as a function argument from the calling module and then your utility function can parse that to extract just the directory and return it which will save you just a little bit of code in each module where you use it, but still will require two lines of code.

Comment: `const __dirname = '.';` HTH

Answer (score 0):

You can't put that code in another module because that other module will always create `__dirname` in the context of that other module, not in the context of the calling module.

As has already been said here, about the best you can do is to create a exported function that you pass `import.meta.url` to as a function argument )(from the calling module) and then your utility function can parse that to extract just the directory and return it which will save you just a little bit of code in each module where you use it, but still will require two lines of code.

**dirname.mjs**

```
import { dirname } from 'path';
import { fileURLToPath } from 'url';

export function makeDirname(metaUrl) {
    return dirname(fileURLToPath(metaUrl));
}
```

**app.js**

```
import { makeDirname } from './dirname.mjs';
const __dirname = makeDirname(import.meta.url);
console.log(__dirname);
```

Comment: You could make it a bit shorter by only passing `import.meta`

Comment: @Bergi - Yep, but I thought the function made more sense passing it the URL than passing it the `meta` object, but you're right, that's another way to do it that saves a few characters of typing.